# TypeORM duplicate Key value for ManyToMany relation

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

**Context**
I use TypeORM and NestJS.
I have two entities :

- workout
- exercise

A workout can I have several exercises and an exercise can have several workouts. To implement this I use a ManyToMany relation.

**Workout entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Workout {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @JoinTable()
  @ManyToMany(() => Exercise, (exercise) => exercise.workouts)
  exercises: Exercise[];

}
```

**Exercise entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Exercise {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Workout, (workout) => workout.exercises)
  workouts: Workout[];
}
```

Everything works well but I got an error message `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` when I try to create a workout with two same exercises.

**Question** : how can I have duplicate entities in a ManyToMany relation ?